# What are some robust Contingent Capital Instrument available?

Tags: banking-regulations, basel, convertible-bond, callable-bonds, contingent-flows

I recently was made aware of the existence of Contingent Capital Instruments like CoCo Bonds. I was wondering if there are other robust options available for Big Banks in this domain?

Comment: Robust in what sense?

Comment: @BobJansen in the sense of well-established theory, pricing and successful application.